# Can I use a .net 4.0 dll assembly reference in a .net 3.5 sharepoint web part?

Tags: visual-web-part, assembly-references

I am using some dll's from the crm 2011 sdk in a .NET 3.5 web part.The target is for SharePoint 2010 online. When I try to build it gives me the following error:

The primary reference "microsoft.xrm.client" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". VisualWebPartProjectWebServiceTest

I cannot upgrade my web part to .NET 4.0 because SharePoint 2010 is not supporting .NET 4.0. Is there some other solution to reference .NET 4.0 dlls in a .NET 3.5 sharepoint webpart?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a .Net 3.5 assembly in a 4.0 project, but not the other way around.